# Не могу выполнить SQL запрос на PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

В чем заключается ошибка моего кода

```
<?php

Class  Database {
    private $link;

    public function __constructor(){
        $this->connect();
    }

    private function connect()
    {
        $config = require_once 'config.php';

        $dsn  = "mysql:host". $config['host'].";dbname=".$config['db_name'].";charset=".$config['charset'];

        $this->link = new PDO($dns, $config['username'], $config['password']);

        return $this;

    }

    public function execute($sql)
    {
        $sth = $this->link->prepare($sql);

        return $sth->execute();
    }

    public function query($sql)
    {
        $sth = $this->link->prepare($sql);

        $sth->execute($sql);

        $result = $sth->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if ($result === false) {return [];}
        return $result;
    }
}

$db = new Database();

print_r($db->query('Select * FROM rating'));
```

В браузере выдает вот такую ошибку:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on
> null in
> C:\Users\Denis\Desktop\OpenServer\domains\localhost\rating.php:31
> Stack trace: #0
> C:\Users\Denis\Desktop\OpenServer\domains\localhost\rating.php(44):
> Database->query() #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\Users\Denis\Desktop\OpenServer\domains\localhost\rating.php on line
> 31

Comment: : Call to a member function prepare() on null in

Прохоже ваше свойство link === null

Comment: И возможно дело в этом 
` "mysql:host". $config['host'].` Нету знака "равно"

Comment: mysql:host=localhost

Comment: А можно спросить, в чем заключается смысл этого класса?

Comment: Я не PHOP разработчик и только учусь. В Youtube создали этот класс. Сам я HTML/CSS/JS

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка однозначно говорит, что вы пытаетесь вызвать метод `prepare` на чём-то, что в данный момент равно `null`. Следовательно, `$this->link` является `null`. Как так? А кто его инициализировать-то будет? Вы его нигде не вызвали.

Ведь специальный метод в PHP, вызываемый при создании объекта класса называется [`__construct`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php), совсем даже не `__constructor`.